# Ratio between clauses and variables

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, satisfiability

How is the ratio between the number of clauses to the number of variables in a HORNSAT sentence correlated with its probability to be satisfied?
My intuition tells me that the more variables I have, the probability increases, and the more clauses I have, the probability decreases. But how can I quantify this correlation?
Also, a related reference will be very helpful.

Comment: For general SAT, see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20095 and related questions for pointers to terminology and related work.